# Scrapy Django Limit links crawled

Tags: python, django, scrapy

I just got scrapy setup and running and it works great, but I have two (noob) questions.  I should say first that I am totally new to scrapy and spidering sites.

1. Can you limit the number of links crawled?  I have a site that doesn't use pagination and just lists a lot of links (which I crawl) on their home page.  I feel bad crawling all of those links when I really just need to crawl the first 10 or so.
2. How do you run multiple spiders at once?  Right now I am using the command `scrapy crawl example.com`, but I also have spiders for example2.com and example3.com.  I would like to run all of my spiders using one command. Is this possible?

Comment: Scraping a site all once may get you barred from that site, and is bad/rude practice. Scrapy is concurrent so its it hitting it all at once with multiple connections. Look in the configuration settings for the timeout setting.

Comment: Do you have any idea about my second question?  It seems like it's probably something really obvious that I am missing.

Comment: To run multiple spiders at once use: `scrapy crawl example.com example2.com example3.com`

Answer (score 2):

for #1: Don't use rules attribute to extract links and follow, write your rule in parse function and yield or return Requests object.

for #2: Try scrapyd

Answer (score 1):

Credit goes to Shane, here https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/scrapy-users/EyG_jcyLYmU

Using a CloseSpider should allow you to specify limits of this sort.

http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/extensions.html#module-scrapy.contrib.closespider

Haven't tried it yet since I didn't need it.  Looks like you also might have to enable as an extension (see top of same page) in your settings file.